# Format output for listing an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having some trouble with listing the contents of a complex array. The array holds sections and subsections for a website.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<table class="listing">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="checkable">#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Date added</th>
                        <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($sections); $i++): ?>
                    <tr <?php if ($i % 2 == 0): ?>class="alt"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <td class="checkable"><?php echo $i+1; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo stripslashes($sections[$i]['name']); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $sections[$i]['type_name']; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                             
                        <td><?php echo $sections[$i]['date_added']; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                        <td>
                            <ul class="listing-actions">
                                <li class="default">Actions</li>                                    
                                <li>                            
                                    <a href="edit-section.php?section_id=<?php echo $sections[$i]['section_id']; ?>">Edit</a>                                        
                                    <form action="delete-section.php" method="post" data-prompt="Are you sure you want to delete this element?" >
                                        <input type="hidden" name="section_id" value="<?php echo $sections[$i]['section_id']; ?>" />
                                        <a href="#">Delete</a>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php if (count($sections[$i]['siblings']) > 0): ?>
                        <?php for ($j = 0; $j < count($sections[$i]['siblings']); $j++): ?>
                        <tr <?php if ($i % 2 != 0): ?>class="alt"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <td class="checkable"><?php echo $j+1; ?></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|_&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo stripslashes($sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['name']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['type_name']; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                             
                            <td><?php echo $sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['date_added']; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                            <td>
                                <ul class="listing-actions">
                                    <li class="default">Actions</li>                                    
                                    <li>                            
                                        <a href="edit-section.php?section_id=<?php echo $sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['section_id']; ?>">Edit</a>                                        
                                        <form action="delete-section.php" method="post" data-prompt="Are you sure you want to delete this element?" >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="section_id" value="<?php echo $sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['section_id']; ?>" />
                                            <a href="#">Delete</a>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                            
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And the output is this: http://cl.ly/image/240C1S2A3J3J

Now here's my question: how can I get the numbering right and how can I get that alternating row color right?

Comment: Use `<ol>` for numbered lists.

Comment: What kind of numbering and highlighting do you expect?

Comment: @ernie, I'm talking about the numbers in the first column. I would like them to be in order. By highlighting I mean to have a grey row, then a white one, then a grey row, then a white one and so on. Now both numbering and highlighting are incorrect.

Comment: @psyche should nested elements have different ordering, or should it go from 1 to 12 in your example?

Comment: @ernie, they should go from 1 to 12.

Comment: If you can support CSS3, I'd recommend removing the existing style and using CSS `nth-child` odd / even depending on your preference.

Comment: Your sibling for loop should check if j % 2 == 0.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler, tried that before posting the question, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loops were causing issues . . . separate variable to keep track of the row is needed . . .

```
<table class="listing">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="checkable">#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Date added</th>
                        <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        $rowNum = 0;
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($sections); $i++): 
                            $rowNum++;
                    ?>
                    <tr <?php if ($rowNum % 2 == 0): ?>class="alt"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <td class="checkable"><?php echo $rowNum; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo stripslashes($sections[$i]['name']); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $sections[$i]['type_name']; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                             
                        <td><?php echo $sections[$i]['date_added']; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                        <td>
                            <ul class="listing-actions">
                                <li class="default">Actions</li>                                    
                                <li>                            
                                    <a href="edit-section.php?section_id=<?php echo $sections[$i]['section_id']; ?>">Edit</a>                                        
                                    <form action="delete-section.php" method="post" data-prompt="Are you sure you want to delete this element?" >
                                        <input type="hidden" name="section_id" value="<?php echo $sections[$i]['section_id']; ?>" />
                                        <a href="#">Delete</a>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php if (count($sections[$i]['siblings']) > 0): ?>
                        <?php 
                           for ($j = 0; $j < count($sections[$i]['siblings']); $j++): 
                           $rowNum++;
                        ?>
                        <tr <?php if ($rowNum % 2 == 0): ?>class="alt"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <td class="checkable"><?php echo $rowNum; ?></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|_&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo stripslashes($sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['name']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['type_name']; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                             
                            <td><?php echo $sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['date_added']; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                            <td>
                                <ul class="listing-actions">
                                    <li class="default">Actions</li>                                    
                                    <li>                            
                                        <a href="edit-section.php?section_id=<?php echo $sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['section_id']; ?>">Edit</a>                                        
                                        <form action="delete-section.php" method="post" data-prompt="Are you sure you want to delete this element?" >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="section_id" value="<?php echo $sections[$i]['siblings'][$j]['section_id']; ?>" />
                                            <a href="#">Delete</a>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                            
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: @Psyche Whoops, forgot to increment the row for the subsections . . . updated code . . .